# How can i combine columns from three tables and show them in one row based on month?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have three tables

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want to take out monthly sum of total_salary from monthly_salaries, monthly sum of amount from deductions and monthly sum of amount from bonuses and show them in my view. I just can't figure out how to do that.

I tried them separately something like below:

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(DATE_FORMAT(date_added, '%m-%Y')), sum(m.total_salary) FROM monthly_salary m GROUP BY month(m.date_added), year(m.date_added);

SELECT ANY_VALUE(DATE_FORMAT(date_added, '%m-%Y')), sum(d.amount) from deductions d GROUP BY month(d.date_added), year(d.date_added);

SELECT ANY_VALUE(DATE_FORMAT(date_added, '%m-%Y')), sum(b.amount) from bonuses b GROUP BY month(b.date_added), year(b.date_added);
```

How can i combine them so that i can get same month sum of salaries , bonuses and deduction in one row?

Comment: Do you also have a table of employees? Do you have employees who have no monthly_salary,bonuses or deductions?

Comment: yes i have employees who have no records in monthly_salary, bonuses and deductions.

Comment: So what;s the boss table in the published data, do you only want results for those where a salary has been paid?

Comment: no i want all of them not just paid

Answer (score 2):

You can select from queries and join them. For the three results you would want full outer joins for the case that a month is missing in one of the tables. Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't support full outer joins. If it is guaranteed that there will never be a month in one table and not in another, you can just inner join:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(LPAD(mnth, 2, 0), '-', yr),
  s.total AS salary,
  d.total AS deduction,
  b.total AS bonus
FROM
(
  SELECT
    month(date_added) AS mnth,
    year(date_added) AS yr,
    sum(total_salary) AS total
  FROM monthly_salary
  GROUP BY month(date_added), year(date_added);
) s
JOIN
(
  SELECT
    month(date_added) AS mnth,
    year(date_added) AS yr,
    sum(amount) AS total
  FROM deductions
  GROUP BY month(date_added), year(date_added);
) d USING (mnth, yr)
JOIN
(
  SELECT
    month(date_added) AS mnth,
    year(date_added) AS yr,
    sum(amount) AS total
  FROM bonuses
  GROUP BY month(date_added), year(date_added);
) b USING (mnth, yr)
ORDER BY yr, mnth;
```

If there can be missing months, select all months first and then left outer join above subqueries:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(LPAD(mnth, 2, 0), '-', yr),
  s.total AS salary,
  d.total AS deduction,
  b.total AS bonus
FROM
(
  SELECT month(date_added) AS mnth, year(date_added) AS yr
  FROM monthly_salary
  UNION
  SELECT month(date_added) AS mnth, year(date_added) AS yr
  FROM deductions
  UNION
  SELECT month(date_added) AS mnth, year(date_added) AS yr
  FROM bonuses
) months
LEFT JOIN (...) s USING (mnth, yr)
LEFT JOIN (...) d USING (mnth, yr)
LEFT JOIN (...) b USING (mnth, yr)
ORDER BY yr, mnth;
```

Comment: Thank you mate your solution led me to my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can JOIN them through common months :

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(DATE_FORMAT(m.date_added, '%m-%Y')), 
       SUM(m.total_salary) AS total_salary,
       SUM(d.amount) AS deductions_amount,
       SUM(b.amount) AS bonuses_amount 
  FROM monthly_salary m
  JOIN deductions d ON month(d.date_added) = month(m.date_added)
  JOIN bonuses b ON month(b.date_added) = month(m.date_added)  
 GROUP BY month(m.date_added), year(m.date_added);
```

Comment: I appreciate the gesture but this does not work right.